# Start Spring maven project with Angular 2+

Tags: java, spring, angular, maven, spring-mvc

I am learning stuff which I wrote in title. I need som good point where to start. Old I found is old sheets for it, so I decide ask to help here. Can you tell me how to start project with these technologies? Do exist some artifact for Spring 5 and Angular least in version 4? Pure spring project I should generate from [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io) but it's for spring boot, and I read boot is not good for beginners, and still without angular. Can you give me some hints? Thanks.

I will be also glad for some git repository with these technologies for inspiration.

Comment: If you don't want to roll your own, try http://www.jhipster.tech

Comment: I prefer hand-code project start, because I better understand what I on project have. But thanks for advice :) I'll try to wait for another and I'll see.

Comment: @DenisStephanov Spring Boot is very good for beginners (too), it just removes all the builderplate needed for a pure Spring application. As far as I know, you will not going to get Angular artifacts for Spring, but rather develop your Angular application separately (using angular-cli and server), and when you are finished you just issue `ng build --prod` command for angular to generate the static files, and add them under `src/main/resources/static` to serve with Spring Boot.

Comment: @helospark ok I consider it. I never see angular and spring in real world example. Can you tell me if exist some wat how to have Angular and Spring in one project, and run it together without copying files how to advice me?

Comment: During the development you can keep Angular and Spring Boot running separately, Spring Boot by default starts on 8080, and Angular has a command `ng serve` that starts on 4200. When doing the final build of the Spring Boot you (or some clever Maven trick) has to copy together the ng build with production profile and the Spring Boot built with prod profile. Other way: angular does not even need to run on the same server, ex. if you have a some front proxy (like Nginx), angular files could reside there, and Spring Boot could be separate (static file-less) application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to notice to the these notes:

1. If you want to use **AngularJs** you can add your angular javascripts to the every html files and use it.
2. ]f you want to use **Angular 2+**, it is difference than AngularJs because Angular 2+ is written with Typescript and then **Transpile** to javascript, Angular 2+ has one html file(index.html) and your javascripts after transpile add to this file.
3. If you want to use both of **Spring and Angular 2+**, you can use Angular project instead of **Client Project** and Spring Project instead of **Backend Project**, and how to these projects communicate each other it's very easy By **Spring API**.
4. And the **Bad Project** is mixing Spring and Angular Project, in these situation you must to try hard to join Angular and Spring.

Comment: So during developing I have to run 2 servers on different ports like @helospark says in comments?

Comment: Yes, That is true,  but notice to CORS

Comment: why do you think mixing spring and angular is bad project